# Apache2 default page - Nextcloud server on ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, apache2

I am trying to run NextCloud Server on Ubuntu Server as software itself.

I have done all the steps properly as mentioned, and I am running it on apache2 on virtual machine.

As this is the file I edited is "/etc/apache2/sites-available/nextcloud.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin ***my mail-id***
DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/
ServerName ***my ip***

Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"

<Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        Dav off
    </IfModule>
    SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

After doing all this, when I put my IP address in the browser, I get this as my output:
[image]

Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you enabled it with `a2ensite nextcloud` ?

Comment: Since you are using IP addressing for virtual host disable the default site as well.

Comment: @Marco Yes sir everything is enabled

Answer (score 0):

To disable the default page of apache run

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

then

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

once you do run this steps it will run your desired page and disable the apache default page